# ffmpeg h264_qsv Coded memory leak

Tags: ffmpeg

I am developing in C++, using libx264 encoder to encode and push rtsp stream, I can see that the program memory will not rise in the task manager, but when I use the h264_qsv encoder, the program memory will slowly rise, this problem is bothered I have been here for a long time, please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the source code you can compile your code with memory sanitizers. Which will pinpoint where the leak happens. Simplest way to do this (in gcc and clang) is adding `-fsanitize=address` option to `C(XX)FLAGS` in your `Makefile`.